# Quel est l'équivalent de « emphasis mine » pour une citation ?

Tags: traduction, citations

Lorsque l'on fait une citation et que l'on souhaite mettre en avant certains passages, il est commun de changer la graisse des caractères (ou encore de souligner).

Dans un contexte formel (article scientifique par exemple), il est indispensable de préciser l'origine de cette mise en avant : est-elle d'origine ou le fait de la personne faisant la citation ?

En anglais, cela s'indique généralement par « *emphasis mine* » entre parenthèses avant la citation, juste après l'indication de la source et avant les deux points.

Quelle est la traduction française, tant au niveau idiomatique (« [emphase mienne](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22emphase%20mienne%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8) » ?  ;)  ) qu'au niveau de l'endroit où placer cet élément ?

Comment: En anglais, [la question a été posée](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/90161/26839). [J'y réponds](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/90195/26839), en mentionnant très fort un cas en français. Si ça intéresse, je reposte ici.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Selon la publication et le style on peut trouver :

> C'est moi qui souligne.

ou

> C'est l'auteur qui souligne.

ou

> Souligné par l'auteur.

Cela se met soit entre parenthèses après le passage mis en relief, soit en note de bas de page.

Précision : on emploie le verbe « souligner » même si l'emphase se fait en mettant le passage en gras. Ici *souligner* ayant le sens de *faire ressortir*.

Comment: De manière surprenante, “C'est moi qui souligne” a [plus de 5000 occurrences](http://scholar.google.fr/scholar?hl=fr&q=%22C%27est+moi+qui+souligne%22&btnG=Rechercher&lr=lang_fr&as_ylo=&as_vis=0) sur Google Scholar, vs. “Souligné par l'auteur” avec [1850 occurrences](http://scholar.google.fr/scholar?hl=fr&q=%22Souligné+par+l%27auteur%22&btnG=Rechercher&lr=lang_fr&as_ylo=&as_vis=0), ou 838 pour “C'est l'auteur qui souligne”. J'utiliserai néanmoins la forme passive pour le ton de mon document. Merci ! :)

Comment: Mmh… En fait, je comprends le pourquoi du “c'est moi” : faisant tout au long de mon document référence aux “auteurs” pour parler des cités, dire “c'est l'auteur qui souligne” ou “souligné par l'auteur” est ambigu. J'irai rejoindre les 5280 autres, tant pis pour le ton !